# SDL_EventState toggle

Tags: c++, sdl

I've been using SDL_EventState as to disable and enable certain events. However for some reason once I set any state to either on or off, no where else in the program can I change it. To explain further, here is my loop.

```
void game::startLoop()
{
    while(QUIT == false)
    {
        getRoomUpdate();
        applySurface(-15, 280, zombie_lefthand, buffer);
        applySurface(455, 280, zombie_righthand, buffer);

        SDL_Flip(buffer);

        SDL_WaitEvent(&gameEvent);
        {
            switch(gameEvent.type)
            {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                QUIT = true;
                break;

                case SDL_KEYUP:
                switch(gameEvent.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_LEFT:
                    if(isTwoWay == true)
                        SDL_EventState(SDL_KEYUP, 1);
                        startLoop();
                        log("Left key pressed.");
                        SDL_EventState(SDL_KEYUP, 0);

                    case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    if(isTwoWay == true)
                        SDL_EventState(SDL_KEYUP, 1);
                        startLoop();
                        log("Right key pressed.");
                        SDL_EventState(SDL_KEYUP, 0);

                    case SDLK_UP:
                    if(isTwoWay == false)
                        SDL_EventState(SDL_KEYUP, 1);
                        startLoop();
                        log("Up key pressed.");
                        SDL_EventState(SDL_KEYUP, 0);

                    default:
                    SDL_EventState(SDL_KEYUP, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with that code?

Comment: I'm trying to only allow KEYUP to register at certain times. We can't have things walking through walls now can we?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you tried someone else's code.
If it worked you could try to transform their code to  something like yours(functionally wise)

Good Luck!
p.s. I think you should use SDL_ENABLE and SDL_DISABLE.